# Stereo Mix: Works with Speakers, Stops working with Headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio

When I am outputting audio through my laptop's built-in speakers, Stereo mix works correctly.

When I am outputting audio through 3.5 mm headphones, Stereo mix does not capture anything.

[Photo details of every combination of scenarios.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2QGq.jpg)

Things I've learned:

- It doesn't matter whether the headphones have a microphone function
  or not.
- It doesn't matter whether headphones are PHYSICALLY plugged in or not, stereo mix only works when audio is output through speakers.

I have been trying to solve this for days and I am desperate for a solution :(

[Here's my system details / audio driver details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROkIh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I DOWNGRADED my audio driver from version 6.9 to version 6.0.1.8186

It is incredibly stupid that downgrading my audio driver fixed my problem.